# How to restrict serialization for the property type Guid?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

```
    public class Pet
    {
      // The default value for the Animal field is "Dog". 
      [DefaultValue(0)]
      public int testinteger { get; set; }

      [DefaultValue (00000000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 000000000000)]
      public Guid testbool { get; set; }
    }

    public class Run
   {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run test = new Run();

        test.SerializeObject("OverrideDefaultValue.xml");
    }

    public void SerializeObject(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pet));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        Pet myPet = new Pet();
        myPet.testinteger = 10;
        mySerializer.Serialize(writer, myPet);
        writer.Close();
    }
  }
```

Here i have used Id property for serialization. I have used the attribute default value. But serialization is not restricted for Id property.

Comment: Have you tried the [`[NonSerializedAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)?

Comment: @Alejandro `XmlSerializer` doesn't care about `[NonSerialized]`, and: `testbool` is not a field (you can't currently use it with automatically implemented properties, although curiously you can use it with field-like events)

Comment: btw; that `[DefaultValue]` attribute isn't doing what you think it is doing; `00000000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 000000000000` is just a fancy way of saying `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the property as internal(Only public property are Serialized)if attributes is not working.

Try checking if the correct attribute is set set an XML attribute above the property to not serialize the property.
    [XmlIgnore]
   or
    [NonSerialized]

Answer (score 0):

This varies per serializer. Since you're using `XmlSerializer`, adding `[XmlIgnore]` is the attribute-based way to do it.

But you can also add:

```
public bool ShouldSerializetestbool() => false;
```

(this is intended for *conditional* serialization, where you *sometimes* want to include a value; the pattern is `public bool ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}()`)

A more interesting example might be:

```
public bool ShouldSerializetestbool() => testbool != Guid.Empty;
```